# Android: using Base64 to encode an Image to String

Tags: android, base64

I downloaded the **Base64.java** from here:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/util/Base64.java

which contains method **encodeToString()** but its very low sized compared to what i had previously. Its just some 750 lines of code.

the previous 1 was downloaded from here:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/iharder/files/

which has 2064 lines of code but doesn't have the method **encodeToString()** instead it has only **encodeToFile()** method.

Which of these is more robust?

My purpose of using **Base64** is to convert a **ByteArray** i get from Camera Api and send it to a **Server**(the encoded string).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you want to send the encoded image to your server, you should encode it into a `String`:

```
byte[] imageBytes = yourByteArray;
String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: So i can just use the low sized Base64??