# Type Conversion: Byte[] to String, String to Byte[]

Tags: java, android, type-conversion

I'm trying for educational purposes, use the camera of Android to get a photo and send this to a webservice using SOAP.

First, the camera send me a `byte[]` array but this isn't serializable and I can't send this to the webservice. Now I'm trying to convert this into a `String` (this type is serializable), and in the webservice reconvert this `String` into a `byte[]` array.

How I can do it?

For example, I'm trying:

```
request.addProperty("photo", (Arrays.toString((byte[])params[0])));
```

How I get this `String` and convert to the original and exactly `byte[]`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would it not be easier to turn it into an image format and serialize that?

Comment: `byte[]` isn't serializable? Serializing is precisely converting to `byte[]`...

Comment: I suggest you use `byte[]` not `Byte[]` as the latter is less efficient.  BTW byte[] is Serializable, you can just sent it as it is.

Comment: Thanks for faster answers.

When I try to send byte[] Android...
06-16 22:10:18.787: W/System.err(19363): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: [B@41180398

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to convert a `byte[]` into a `String`, use an intermediate serialization meant for arbitrary byte data, such [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). `String`s are for character data, not arbitrary `byte[]`s.

[Android's `Base64` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) makes the above trivial.

This question is pretty much a duplicate of [Android: using Base64 to encode an Image to String](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13026443/139010).

Answer (score 1):

If your web-service only supports ASCII input you can encode your data in base 64: [Base64 Encoding in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109588/base64-encoding-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use it to send byte[] to a Webservice and Decode it.
Thanks!

ANDROID SOAP SERVICE:

```
request.addProperty("photo", Base64.encodeToString((byte[])params[0], Base64.DEFAULT));
```

SOAP WEBSERVICE

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();                    
byte[] a = decoder.decodeBuffer(VAR);
```